# Does the polarity of my AC adapter match that of the device?

Tags: ac, polarity

Looking at the symbols, I think the polarity matches the adapter and device (tip positive), however the design of the symbol is different which is is confusing me, so I want to be 100% certain that they are a match.

Polarity symbol on device:

[image: Polarity symbol on device]

Polarity symbol on AC adapter:

[image: Polarity symbol on AC adapter]

Is it safe to use the adapter with the device? (volts and amps match)

Comment: Consumer electronics usage questions are off-topic on EE.SE.  This stack is about electrical engineering and design.

Comment: This 'helpful to others' question is within the ethos of this site. Getting the power input correct is fundamental to making 'projects' work.

Comment: Andsmith - Both show centre as positive. Both show outside a negative. The two are equivalent as far as polarity goes. As john D says - there are other factors which are relevant as well.

Comment: @Russell  I appreciate your point of view, but this thread will get closed.  If we don't do anything about consumer electronics questions, and search engines find out about it, then we will get swamped with consumer electronics questions.  If you want more of Nick's thinking about this, you and Nick can go chat or meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The polarity is correct, however there's sometimes more than volts and amps to worry about.  Some inexpensive adapters have very high ripple, poor regulation and poor tolerance.  So while it will likely work, there is still a little risk that you may have problems.

Comment: Could chuck a scope on it to see the ripples :)